# Как объединить mp4 и avi

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i video.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

В логах. Что то не получается.

```
[mpegts @ 0000000004abcd40] Invalid timestamps stream=1, pts=21678750, dts=21686220, size=1035
[mp4 @ 00000000050453a0] Invalid DTS: 21480210 PTS: 21476520 in output stream 0:0, replacing by guess
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, где-то у вас mpegts. Во вторых, используйте фильтр или протокол concat: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat и http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1 и http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat и http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate - всё официальные ресурсы.